# How do I get a new Facebook Graph session?

Tags: facebook, session, facebook-graph-api

I am curious as to how sessions/the graph work.

I got the example code off the php sdk and have finally got it working.

So i connect to facebook, the user authorizes the app, it redirects to my website, and i put the users facebook id into my database. The users actions can then be posted onto fb.

When i then try in Internet Explorer (no session), the user logs into my site but when they do an action it is NOT posted to facebook.. because there is no session.. but the user has authorized it.

How do i go about getting a new session for the user when they login to my site given that they HAVE authorized my site on fb...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is an iframe application, it's probable that [IE is blocking your session cookie for being a third party cookie without a P3P header](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/TheImportanceOfP3PAndACompactPrivacyPolicy.aspx).